# How can i receive the hardware key button event On Windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

**How can i receive the hardware key button event On Windows phone 8 App?**

I have many problem,
The WP 8 is available features are very limited.
The Windows CE / WM is a very different behavior.

**I want to access the OS Layer by the API (Function)**

- Back button : Success. I found this key event.
- Home button : ??? (I don't know)
- Search button : ??? (I don't know)
- Volume Up / Down : Just working volume.
- Camera Key : Can i change the default camera app?

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202963(v=vs.105).aspx
- Power Key : Can i optionally lock the power key?
- OEM Key (Barcode Key) : Push the button, I want to execute the My App?

[Additional]

Sorry. My Project information was too little provided.
I developed the WP8 App in the WP Device OEM Manufacturers.
So I can access to "OS, Device Driver, App".
But there are various MS documents, By First Time, The developement is too hard.

Have you ever used these methods can I?
 - Named Event
 - SendMessage / PostMessage
 - Other Communication

I guess the Key-Point "How can i communicate Device driver <-> App"

I am studying now the following Function.
 - Service Agent
 - IPC

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the majority of those buttons, by design. By not allowing applications access, it means the end user has a consistent experience with the standard platform.

You can create a new "[lens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206990%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)" to act as a replacement for the default camera application.

That's not to say though as an OEM, that Microsoft would not provide additional access that is not available to a standard "Store" application. That type of access is often protected by a non-disclosure statement however.

Comment: thanks for you comment.I added the our project infomation. do you have any other advice?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a **public** document that contains the details? Nothing confidential please.

Comment: Sorry, the my company was setting the security on the All document (Doc, Excel, PDF).
So, other PC could not open the files.........

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm so sorry.
Document cannot be provided to anyone security issue.
I will try to consult on microsoft.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd appreciate you accepting my answer as it's the best "public" information that can be provided legally.