# Add Event Listener to buttons "Back, Start, Search" on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-phone

I try to listen if the user is pressing one of the buttons: [Back, Start or Search](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/phones-and-hardware/the-three-buttons-back-start-and-search) (<- not available anymore) , on a Windows Phone, and simply output an alert if this is the case

e.g. `alert("user pressed start");`

Is this possible?

I'm trying to find out if the user is about to close the browser and execute a function before he does. On desktop browsers this is easily done with `onbeforeunload`, but this does not seem to work on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Those are hardware buttons, handled by the OS, not your website, so no, You can't do that.

Comment: Is there nothing like an API or some workaround which allows me to do this? Keyboard buttons on a normal computer are also hardware buttons, handled by the OS, so where is the problem?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this answer: [Bind to mobile device hardware buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293287/bind-to-mobile-device-hardware-buttons)

Basically if you make an hybrid app with a framework such as Cordova Phonegap you can bind an event listeners to physical buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive key events for the back button and the camera button.

as you see here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207557 .

Some help:
 ([How can i receive the hardware key button event On Windows phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268725/how-can-i-receive-the-hardware-key-button-event-on-windows-phone-8))

By the way, i think isn't worth the trouble.
These keys are intended for exclusive use of the OS and you won't have any real benefit for your app by hacking that behaviour.

Comment: What i try is to simply fire a function if someone is on my website and presses the home button.

Comment: Luckily is not possible.

Comment: I also think so, but there must be a workaround for this